# How to escape null characters .i.e [' '] while using regex split function?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string

`text=\\u0932\\u095c\\u0915\\u0940` which i want to escape the `\\u` characters. I am using python regex module to achive this.Below is the command I am using.

`re.split(r'\\u',text)`

which is giving me the following output.

`['', '0932', '095c', '0915', '0940']`

However I want the following output.

`['0932', '095c', '0915', '0940']`

Can anybody please explain as to why I am getting the initial null character
i.e. [''] and how do I escape it using regex. I am new in this domain so any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can't you just remove the empty string in the beginning?

Comment: what about `re.split(r'\\u',text)[1:]` or `re.split(r'\\u',text[3:])`?

Comment: yeah, I could absolute do that. I was just wondering if it could be done using a regex.

Comment: The `split` function "Split string by the occurrences of pattern. " (See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)). If you'll run: `re.split(r'\\u','\\u')` you'll get: `['', '']` because the string '\\u' is getting splitted by `\\u` and the result is everything that comes *before* `\\u` and everything that comes *after* `\\u` and in our case both of them are empty strings. Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for the explanation @alfasin

Comment: Thanks, @Wiktor Stribiżew  for the link.

Comment: Sure thing, and you'll find many ways to remove it, one of the simplest would be to use filter: `filter(None, ['', '0932', '095c', '0915', '0940'])`

Comment: yeah, I used the filter function, it worked for me.